# All not equal to zero - meaning?

Tags: meaning

I have the following sentence in a scientific paper.

“Here r, r1, and r2 are all not equal to zero.”

Does this mean that if one of them is zero, then the condition is not met? Or does it mean that at the same time they cannot be zero?

For example, is r=1, r1=2, and r2=0 a good input?

Comment: The operative word is "all". If any one of them is zero, then it not true that **all** of them are not zero. This is simply a question in Boolean logic, not in English.

Comment: *“Here r, r1, and r2 are all not equal to zero.”* This is not a condition, it is a statement of fact: neither r, r1, nor r2 is equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

"all not equal to zero" means that r is not equal to zero, r1 is not equal to zero, *and* r3 is not equal to zero.

"not all equal to zero" means that *at least one* of them is nonzero, and the others could still be zero.

However, people do not always* obey this distinction. When you see a sentence like this you often have to guess the author's intent.

* (see the difference between "do not always" and "always do not"?)

Answer (score 1):

It is formally ambiguous.

In context, I believe it means that all of them are non-zero.

Comment: It is not ambiguous at all. **All not** means *none*. **Not all** means *no more than all*.

Comment: We're talking about English, not logic. _All that glisters is not gold_ was old when Shakespeare used it. And I don't know what you intend by _no more than all_, but sinxe _more than all_ is incoherent, it doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

“Here r, r1, and r2 are all not equal to zero.”

Usually "not equal to zero" is found in math and science texts as "non-zero".  As I read the sentence, it would be the same as and more clear as “Here r, r1, and r2 are all non-zero.”

All values are non-zero:
r NOT EQUAL 0
r1 NOT EQUAL 0
r2 NOT EQUAL 0